# Mediawiki API error: Unrecognized value for parameter 'prop': extracts

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have a new installation of mediawiki. I am trying to use the API to simply get an article. The API url I am using is:

https://example.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=Vendor_cisco

Upon going to that URL I get: Unrecognized value for parameter 'prop': extracts

This seems odd because all of the following urls do work and return the right data:

https://example.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=links&titles=Vendor_cisco
https://example.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=categories&titles=Vendor_cisco
https://example.com/mediawiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Vendor_cisco

How do I get the body and text from my article? I was under the impression prop=extracts is what is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`prop=extracts` is part of TextExtracts extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API) (formerly [MobileFrontend extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend#prop.3Dextracts)). If you don't have that extension installed, you won't be able to use `prop=extracts`.

Comment: I added the TextEctracts extension and also the MobileFrontend and installed it like the instrucions on mediawiki, but the error remains?