# Mediawiki API error: "Unrecognized value for parameter 'prop': extracts"

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I`am using the Mediawiki API offline on my server.

I installed everything and it works but if i try a query it returns the error: `"Unrecognized value for parameter 'prop': extracts"` than i installed the [TextExtracts extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API) and also the [MobileFrontend extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend#prop.3Dextracts), but it's still not working.

I tried this from the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960533/mediawiki-api-error-unrecognized-value-for-parameter-prop-extracts) question.

My url:

`api.php?action=parse&page=Paul_McCartney&prop=extracts&format=xml`

error:

http://prntscr.com/9y6df7

Mediawiki versions:

http://prntscr.com/9y6d01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextExtracts extension implements a `query` Api module, so you can't use the `extracts` prop with the `parse` action. Instead of your url, you can use:

`api.php?action=query&page=Paul_McCartney&prop=extracts&format=xml`
*(see the action parameter, which changed from `parse` to `query`)*

to get the `extracts` prop.